# Websites DNS has changed everywhere but the clients building. Is this a cache issue?

Tags: caching, dns

We recently launched a new website for a client and in the process we had to change the DNS to a new IP. The change has taken place everywhere but the clients office. I had the client run nslookup form there computer and this is what we got.

Server:pjasbs.corp.pjaa.com
IP: 10.00.10

Name:[website URL]
Server: [incorrect IP]

It looks like they are running into an internal cache problem but this is out of my realm of knowledge. Any advice on fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, clear the Cache, then retry.

Hope this helps - Jim

Comment: Is this a server side cache? Or can this be done on individual computers? Any resources on how to get this done? This stuff is not my forte.

Comment: As StenSoft said: You can either wait (the usual TTL is 2 days so it takes no more than 2 days for the cache to expire) or reload/restart the client's DNS resolving server to flush its cache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears so.  If the client uses an ISP to provide their internet access, they are at the mercy of the ISP DNS.  If not, they need to run flushdns on their DNS daemon.

Comment: Unfortunately it has been about a week with no changes.

Comment: Somewhere in their devices, their router or on their computers themselves is the dns ip.  Track it down.  Then have a shorter TTL (time to live) set on the DNS daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait (the usual TTL is 2 days so it takes no more than 2 days for the cache to expire) or reload/restart the client's DNS resolving server to flush its cache.